# Make a new column in Pandas dataframe by adding multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm just a beginner and I have a dataframe with multiple columns like this

```
A   B   C   D
2   4   6   8
1   3   5   7
1   2   3   4
```

The names of the column A-D are its date. For example, April 1, April 2, April 3, etc. But the dataframe also includes previous months.

How do I make a new column and get the sum for April only?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If your dataframe looks like:

```
>>> df
   March 29  March 30  March 31  April 1  April 2  April 3  April 4
0         9         5         4        7        4        4        2
1         6         7         7        2        7        3        6
2         3         5         8        9        8        2        2
3         9         1         8        3        5        9        3
4         9         1         1        3        9        2        9
```

First, build list of month groups by splitting column names in two parts:

- [0] → month name
- [1] → day

```
months = [month for month, _ in df.columns.str.split()]
```

```
>>> months
['March', 'March', 'March', 'April', 'April', 'April', 'April']
```

Then, group and sum for each month along columns axis:

```
out = df.groupby(months, axis="columns").sum()
```

```
>>> out
   April  March
0     17     18
1     18     20
2     21     16
3     20     18
4     23     11
```

**Edit**: column names as `datetime` (like `2021-01-01 00:00:00`)

```
>>> df
   2020-03-29  2020-03-30  2020-03-31  2020-04-01  2020-04-02  2020-04-03  2020-04-04
0           9           5           4           7           4           4           2
1           6           7           7           2           7           3           6
2           3           5           8           9           8           2           2
3           9           1           8           3           5           9           3
4           9           1           1           3           9           2           9
```

Convert your columns name from string to datetime (if needed):

```
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns)
```

The rest remains unchanged:

```
months = df.columns.strftime("%B")
out = df.groupby(months, axis="columns").sum()
```

```
>>> out
   April  March
0     17     18
1     18     20
2     21     16
3     20     18
4     23     11
```

Comment: What if the column names are for example, 2021-01-01 00:00:00? It's being read as datetime format and couldn't be read as a column name properly.